# What password does an Azure App Service Certificate have when exported as PFX? Is it possible to change it?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, pfx

I have purchased an App Service Certificate from Azure, but I need to change the password of it to install it in an Application Gateway. What is the password of the certificate by default? How would I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default password of the App Service Certificate when exported as PFX is empty, but as you say you cannot import it to the Application Gateway as it needs a password (other services in Azure do too). In order to change it, you can run this commands with OpenSSL (download: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries):

Export the PFX and private key to .pem:

openssl pkcs12 -in .\old.pfx -out old.pem -nodes

Then create a new PFX:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out .\new.pfx -in old.pem

In Windows you can import it in your machine, mark the key as exportable when importing it (there is a menu for this), and then after installing it locally, export it. Make sure to click in "export private key"

Comment: Thank you very much Ignacio, this was exactly what I needed. I followed the steps you outlined and was able to change the password.